# Extract numbers followed by specific text

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am new to Regex and I am looking to write a Regex to extract any kind of numbers (like 23,23a,24-26) which are immediately followed by a text which is surrounded by !.

More explanation:
Need to match numbers (simple numbers, the range of numbers separated by a dash or a number followed by a letter (a,b,c,d,..)) that are immediately followed by itself (ignoring commas) and a text surrounded by !

For example in the below text, I am looking for the part which I made *Italic*

> ;   *46-58     !some text!* ;  , 5 some text, 3-21  , 6-22 some text, 16 some text   !some text! ;   46-58 some text, *5     !some text!* ;   3-21  , 6-22 some text, 16 some text, some text !some text! ;   46-58 some text, 5 some text, *3-21 ,23a , 6-22     !some text!* ;

To make it clearer, I made the text that I am interested Red.
[image]

So far I came up with the following Regex

`\![\w\s]*\!`  => find the text surrounded by `!`

`[a-z]?[\s|,]? [\-|,| |  |   |     |    |0-9|-|\d+[\-|a-z]*\d*]*\![\w\s]*\!` => this one select everything between two consecutive `;`

`\d+[-,]*[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*\s*[,]*` => this one select any kind of numbering

But so far,  I was not able to put them together to select what I want.

Comment: show what values should be matched

Comment: Shoulf 23a be matched as well?

Comment: Yes , 23a should also match. I made Italic the parts that should match. Thank you

Comment: Why the 3-21 from the end of the text should be matched when the first occurrence of it (which is exactly the same) should not?

Comment: Because the first one is not surrounded by !

Comment: The parts with words bound by `!` are regular enough. But I don't quite get how the *number* part is regular? Can they contain all chars? Or only `a` and `-` and commas and white spaces?!!

Comment: Thank jrook, they are street numbers. So we may have 25,25a,25-55,57c XYZ street. Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/TSfjiS/1) can be a start. It matches the parts you have marked. But I am not sure if it encompasses all the patterns you want to match.

Comment: In general, if the street numbers are too irregular (to a degree that are indistinguishable from the parts bounded by `!`, then maybe regex is not the tool you want to use. I think will need to split the string by `!***!` sections and then try to somehow parse the address based on the rules you have.

Comment: None of the two (three in fact) are surrounded by `!` you need to exaplain what is your concept of "surrounded" because the only thing they are surrounded with is with `,` or the other texts that are surrounded with `!` like `!some text!` this requirements makes no sense

Comment: @JorgeCampos: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/TSfjiS/1). I think he wants to match some pattern immediately before parts bounded by `!`s.

Comment: Thank Jrook, I tried it in C#. It picks the correct ones, and I can do the rest by programming (check to see whether this has follows by !). This was really helpful and I really appreciate that.

Comment: Belive me jrook, the text was so messy, at least I was able to find the street names correctly by C# and openstreetmap. However, you helped to detect numbers followed by ! and appreciate that. I can do the rest.

Comment: @jrook Ok, now I understand. So his requirement should be written as: Need to match numbers (simple numbers, range of numbers separated by dash or a number followed by a letter) that are immediately followed by itself (ignoring commas) and a text surrounded by `!`

Comment: @jrook You should provide that as an answer. You will have my upvote.

Comment: Thank @Jorge, I will edit the question. I thought the title was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to match a pattern immediately before the parts of the text bounded by `!` symbols. I think the exact answer will depend on this *pattern* that is to be matched. It might not be a good fit for regular expressions after all.

I created [this](https://regex101.com/r/TSfjiS/1) example (javascript) that matches the expressions in the question.

**Note:**
I made some assumptions about the pattern that is to be matched. Namely, the pattern starts with a digit and can only contain digits, dashes, commas, and character `a`.

Comment: it may also contain b, c,.or a few more, I have added them based on what you wrote. Much appreciated. Thanks a lot for your answer, and also making the assumptions clear.